# Garbage socket client nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, server, client, disconnect

I'm a new in nodejs, i have project about TCP server client , I init 2000 client and send to server 1KB/1s on terminal, after i click X button on terminal (disconnect client unusual). 
On my server, only 1500-1600 client disconnect, the rest client still not disconnect ?? 
So how can i clean this garbage connection ??
How can i check status of socket ??

Client code :

```
var test = setInterval(function () {
var client = socks.connect(function (socket) {
    lstClient.push(socket);
    var message = '';
    console.log('>> Connection successful');
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data.length);

    });
    var myTimer = setInterval(function () {
        if (socket.writable) socket.write(datareal.toString());
        else clearInterval(myTimer);
    }, 5000);

    socket.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    socket.on('close', function () {
        console.log('Disconnect socket...');
        socket.destroy();
    });
})
```

}, 15);

Thanks to advance !!